# How to show Year{a,b} in citation with papers published in the same year, but have a long list of authors (with same first author)

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib

I have a document where 2 papers are cited with the same first author and the same year. But there is a long list of authors as shown in the example below. As you can see, the citations are added to the document, but the second one gets and `?`. The paper is in the bibliography at the end of the report, but it seems LaTeX don't know how to deal with it in the main document. Is there a way to make it replace the `?` with the proper citation (Brady et al. 2019b) and the first being (Brady et al. 2019a)?

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{report} 
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{mycitations.bib}
@article{Brady:2019fe,
author = {Brady, Steven P and Bolnick, Daniel I and Barrett, Rowan Douglas H. and Chapman, Lauren and Crispo, Erika and Derry, Alison M and Eckert, Christopher G and Fraser, Dylan J and Fussmann, Gregor F and Gonzalez, Andrew and Guichard, Frederic and Lamy, Thomas and Lane, Jeffrey and McAdam, Andrew G and Newman, Amy E M and Paccard, Antoine and Robertson, Bruce and Rolshausen, Gregor and Schulte, Patricia M and Simons, Andrew M and Vellend, Mark and Hendry, Andrew P},
    journal = {The American Naturalist},
    language = {English},
    number = {4},
    pages = {495--515},
    pmid = {31490718},
    rating = {0},
    title = {{Understanding maladaptation by uniting ecological and evolutionary perspectives}},
    volume = {194},
    year = {2019}}

@article{testestest,
    author = {Brady, Steven P and Bolnick, Daniel I and Angert, Amy L and Gonzalez, Andrew and Barrett, Rowan Douglas H. and Crispo, Erika and Derry, Alison M and Eckert, Christopher G and Fraser, Dylan J and Fussmann, Gregor F and Guichard, Frederic and Lamy, Thomas and McAdam, Andrew G and Newman, Amy E M and Paccard, Antoine and Rolshausen, Gregor and Simons, Andrew M and Hendry, Andrew P},
    journal = {Evolutionary Applications},
    number = {7},
    pages = {1229--1242},
    rating = {0},
    title = {{Causes of maladaptation}},
    volume = {12},
    year = {2019}}

\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage[sectionbib]{bibunits}
\defaultbibliographystyle{chicago} 
\defaultbibliography{mycitations}

\begin{document}
\bibliographyunit[\chapter]

\setcitestyle{authoryear,round,aysep={},yysep={,},notesep={ }}

This is a duDDDEEEEEE, be careful: \citep{Brady:2019fe}.
\citet{Brady:2019fe,testestest}.
\cite{Brady:2019fe}
\cite{testestest}

\tableofcontents

\bibliographystyle{chicago}
\bibliography{mycitations}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is a known problem with the `chicago.bst` which is a very old style, and not designed for use with `natbib`. I would recommend using `biblatex-chicago` instead. `biblatex` can also implement your `bibunits` functionality but the `bibunits` package itself can't be used.

Comment: Is there a fix for this (using another `.bst` file for example?)

Comment: Yes, depending on how faithful you need to be the the actual Chicago style. But if you just need generic author/year style then `apalike` would probably suffice or any of the `natbib` basic styles: `agms`, `kluwer` or `dcu`.